# Ubuntu 16.04 on AWS EC2: How to automount additional devices at boot?

Tags: amazon-ec2, mount, amazon-ebs

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on an Amazon AWS EC2 instance. I've a xvda1 root but I've just created, after the instance launch two more EBS disks.

Actual situation:

```
$ df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            511M     0  511M   0% /dev
tmpfs           104M  3.2M  101M   4% /run
/dev/xvda1       11G  2.2G  7.8G  22% /
tmpfs           520M     0  520M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           520M     0  520M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           104M     0  104M   0% /run/user/1000


$ cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   defaults,discard        0 0

$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0  10G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0  10G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0   8G  0 disk
xvdc    202:32   0  12G  0 disk
```

I've already created an ext4 partition on each of xvdb and xvdc.

How can I automount these new virtual disks on boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a pretty neat [guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html) on how to do this, provided by AWS. Basically, you get the UUID for the new partition, format it as ext4 and add it to fstab. The steps are:

1. Use the lsblk command to view your available disk devices and their
   mount points (if applicable) to help you determine the correct
   device name to use.

   [ec2-user ~]$ lsblk
2. Get the UUID with:

   [ec2-user ~]$ sudo file -s /dev/xvda1
   /dev/xvda1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=1701d228-e1bd-4094-a14c-8c64d6819362 (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)
3. Format the partition and create a filesystem:

   [ec2-user ~]$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvda1
4. Mount it to test that it works:

   [ec2-user ~]$ sudo mount device_name destination
5. Add it to `/etc/fstab`, with the below example syntax (careful not to mess it up):

   UUID=de9a1ccd-a2dd-44f1-8be8-2d4275cb85a3       /data   ext4    defaults,nofail        0       2
6. Test with:

   [ec2-user ~]$ sudo mount -a